# HTML + CSS image & text stick together nextline?

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

I would like to make the leaf image and the text stick together if it has to go to the next line.

[image]

I tried many things but can't figure out how.

Thanks in advance,

Here is the code of the text:

```
<div id="ingredients">
    <img style="width: 25px;;padding-right: 1%;" src=" https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/Leaf_icon_15.svg/1200px-Leaf_icon_15.svg.png" alt="" />
    <div class="tooltiping" style="color: black;"> Butyrospermum Parkii Butter,&nbsp;
        <span class="tooltiptext">unknown</span>
    </div>
    <img style="width: 25px;padding-right: 1%;" src=" https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/Leaf_icon_15.svg/1200px-Leaf_icon_15.svg.png" alt="" />
    <div class="tooltiping" style="color: black;"> Zhea Corn Starch,&nbsp;
        <span class="tooltiptext">unknown</span>
    </div>
    <img style="width: 25px;padding-right: 1%;" src=" https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/Leaf_icon_15.svg/1200px-Leaf_icon_15.svg.png" alt="" />
    <div class="tooltiping" style="color: black;"> Helianthus Annuus Seed Oil,&nbsp;
        <span class="tooltiptext">unknown</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltiping" style="color: black;">Sodium Bicarbonate,&nbsp;
        <span class="tooltiptext">unknown</span>
    </div>
        <img style="width: 25px;padding-right: 1%;" src=" https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/Leaf_icon_15.svg/1200px-Leaf_icon_15.svg.png" alt="" />
    <div class="tooltiping" style="color: black; "> Prunus Armeniaca Kernel Oil,&nbsp;s
        <span class="tooltiptext">unknown</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltiping" style="color: black;">Parfum,&nbsp;
        <span class="tooltiptext">unknown</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltiping" style="color: black;">Tocopherol,&nbsp;
        <span class="tooltiptext">unknown</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltiping" style="color: black;"><i>Geraniol</i>,&nbsp;
        <span class="tooltiptext">unknown</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltiping" style="color: black;"><i>Linalool</i>,&nbsp;
        <span class="tooltiptext">unknown</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltiping" style="color: black;"><i>Citronellol</i>,&nbsp;
        <span class="tooltiptext">unknown</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltiping" style="color: black;"><i>Citral</i>,&nbsp;
        <span class="tooltiptext">unknown</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltiping" style="color: black;"><i>Farnesol</i>,&nbsp;
        <span class="tooltiptext">unknown</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltiping" style="color: black;"><i>Limonen</i>.
        <span class="tooltiptext">unknown</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you not use the `::before` pseudo element?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works ! 
I used :

```
.pdflink:after {
    background-image: url('/images/pdf.png');
    background-size: 10px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px; 
    height: 20px;
    content:"";
}
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could put the image inside the DIV and use a non-breaking space between image and first letter:

```
<div class="tooltiping" style="color: black;"><img style="width: 25px;;padding-right: 1%;" src=" https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/Leaf_icon_15.svg/1200px-Leaf_icon_15.svg.png" alt="" />&nbsp;Butyrospermum Parkii Butter,&nbsp;
    <span class="tooltiptext">unknown</span>
</div>
```